# If the difference in consecutive elements of a sequence converges to $0$, do consecutive subsequences converge to the same limit point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_k\}$ be bounded sequence of real numbers with a convergent subsequence $\{x_{k_j} \}$, where $x_{k_j} \to x_*$ as $j \to \infty$. If $$\lim_{k \to \infty} | x_{k+1} - x_k | = 0, $$

does $x_{{k_j}+1} \to x_*$ as $j \to \infty$?

Is the proof as simple as taking the limit of $|x_{k+1} - x_k|$ along the subsequence? I am rusty on this level of analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! $|x_{k_j+1} - x_*| = |x_{k_j+1} - x_{k_j}+ x_{k_j} - x_*|  \le |x_{k_j+1} - x_{k_j}| + |x_{k_j} - x_*|$. The limit of the first term as $j\to \infty$ is zero by the assumption that the successive differences tend to zero, and as $j\to \infty$ the second term tends to zero since $x_*$ is the limit of the subsequence $x_{k_j}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would say it's basically that easy, with the help of a little triangle inequality. We have
$$
|x_{k_j+1} - x_*| \le |x_{k_j+1} - x_{k_j}| + |x_{k_j} - x_*| \underset{j\to \infty}{\to} 0.
$$